# Why is this wrong (Permutations)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Question: Given two strings s1 and s2, write a function to return true if s2 contains the permutation of s1. In other words, one of the first string's permutations is the substring of the second string.

(From Leetcode)

Examples:

Input:

```
s1 = "ab"
s2 = "eidbaooo"
```

Output: `True`

Explanation: `s2` contains one permutation of `s1` ("ba").

Input:

```
s1= "ab"
s2 = "eidboaoo"
```

Output: `False`

```
isperm = False
for i in range(len(s2)-len(s1)+1):
    if sorted(s2[i : i+len(s1)]) == sorted(s1):
        isperm = True
return isperm
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your code that you are asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is a brute force, is not a desired solution for this problem and most of medium and hard questions on LeetCode.

This'll pass through:

```
class Solution:
    def checkInclusion(self, a, b):
        count_map_a = collections.Counter(a)
        count_map_b = collections.Counter(b[:len(a)])

        for i in range(len(a), len(b)):
            if count_map_a == count_map_b:
                return True

            count_map_b[b[i]] += 1
            count_map_b[b[i - len(a)]] -= 1
            if count_map_b[b[i - len(a)]] == 0:
                del(count_map_b[b[i - len(a)]])

        return count_map_b == count_map_a
```

We don't need to use `sorted` for this problem. Instead, we'd use two `Counter`s.

Sorted is a O(N Log N) time complexity, when we'd run it through a for loop of Order of N, the time complexity would become O(N ^ 2 Log N). Our goal is to find the most efficient algorithm with lowest time complexity first, then we'd possibly consider to reduce our memory to the lowest.

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/discuss) which you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions in there, with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including efficient algorithms and asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.
- Brute force algorithms usually get accepted for [easy](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Easy) questions. For [medium](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Medium) and [hard](https://leetcode.com/problemset/all/?difficulty=Hard) questions, about 90% of the time, brute force algorithms fail mostly with [Time Limit Exceeded](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/) (TLE) and less with Memory Limit Exceeded (MLE) errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import itertools as itt
def isPerm(s1, s2):
    for s in itt.permutations(s1, len(s1)):
        if ''.join(s) in s2:
            return True
    return False

s1= "ab"
s2 = "eidboaoo"
isPerm(s1, s2)
```

Comment: This honestly sounds like a terrible idea

Comment: @mad physicist: why so?

Comment: Because if the first string has more than a couple of elements, you will spend forever brute-forcing a task that should be blindingly fast.